# Connect to Mir from terminal?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mir

I'm trying to connect to Mir from the terminal in Ubuntu Touch, or more correct, the coreapp app mediaplayer-app is. I'm starting mediaplayer-app, but it can't find any mir-server. The mir server is running, as the whole graphical environment is running, and as I started the terminal application.

The use case is that I want to start a video from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case you can use `ubuntu-app-launch` followed by the app name. This sets things up so that the app can connect to Mir. I'm not sure about the media player app specifically though, nor about parameters.